# Writing Integers to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, text-files

New to Python, I am writing integers to a text file for a program, but once the numbers go above 10 the program fails to work. Therefore, I want to add a space after every integer, I have tried a few ways to do this but however it's not been working.

Here is one way in which I tried to do so:

```
positions = int(uq_words.index(i) + 1, (" "))
```

I added the `(" ")`.

I realise that this is probably a really basic problem to solve.

Comment: not clear what you want. to write to file you use `with open('filename', 'w') as f:` and then f.write('whatever you want to write')

Comment: Ahh, I want to write the contents of the variable `positions` - however, whenever I try to write the integers to the text file, I get an error saying `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You need to learn about [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Also see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting But in the mean time you can do `positions =  str(uq_words.index(i) + 1) + ' '`, assuming that `uq_words.index(i) + 1` is the integer you want to print or save to the file, then `positions` will contain the desired string.

Comment: a=2 this is int; str(a) will become string; you can check using type() function

Answer (score 1):

try something like `" ".join(uq_words)` and then write to file